# Error segmentation violation core using threads on C Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have this code

```
void *recorreNumeroH (void *arg){
struct Data *datosH;
datosH = (struct Data *) arg;
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
int t = 0, numero = 0 ,primo = -1;
char linea[13];
FILE *entrada;
FILE *salida;
printf("%i   %i  %s\n",datosH->id, datosH->lineasT, datosH->nomT);
entrada = fopen("entrada.txt","r");
rewind(entrada);
fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),entrada);
salida = fopen (datosH -> nomT ,"w"); 
int cont=0; 
while ((fscanf(entrada, "%i", &numero) != EOF) && (cont != datosH -> lineasT)){
    primo = numprimo(numero);
    fprintf(salida, "%i  %i\n",numero,primo);
    cont++;
} 
fclose(salida);
fflush(stdin);
fclose(entrada);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
return NULL;
}
```

this is how i put it in a thread

```
    struct Data *data;                                                  
    pthread_t t1;
    while (contP!=numero2){                                                                     
        contP++;                                                                                
        sprintf(pro, "t%d.txt", contP); 
        strcpy(data->nomT,pro);                                                 
        printf("Aca esa el archivo salida:%s\n",pro);                                                   
        if (numero2-contP!=1){                                                                  
            lineasT=t/numero2;  
            data->lineasT=lineasT;                                                              
            printf("(%d/%d) = %d \n",t,numero2,lineasT);
        }                                                                               
        else{                                                                                   //Si es el penultimo
                lineasT=(t/numero2)+(t%numero2);
                data->lineasT=lineasT;                                                      
                printf("(%d/%d)+(%dmod%d) = %d \n",t,numero2,t,numero2,lineasT);
        }
        int l = pthread_create(&t1,NULL,recorreNumeroH,(void *) data);
        printf("se creo? %d\n",l);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
```

EDIT:
I create a struct like some of you said, rewrite some parts of *recorreNumero* but it keeps giving me the error segmentation violation core

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: The `malloc()` function is required to be thread-safe.  It is not the direct cause of your problem.  Rule of thumb: it isn't the system that's at fault; it is *your* code that is wrong.  That goes whether you've been programming 10 minutes or 10 years (or longer).

Comment: Have you worked out which line it is crashing on? Try running it in a debugger and it should tell you and then you can update the question with this useful and vital piece of information

Comment: 'pthread_create(&t1,NULL,recorreNumero(entrada,pro,lineasT),NULL);' - no.  That is a fuction call, not a function pointer.  Anyway, there is one signature for thread functions, and that does not comply:(

Comment: i bet the compiler is complaining big time about this. as martin points out your pthread-create is completely wrong

Comment: the changes you have made look good. What do you mean 'it passes nothing'? What did you see in args in the debugger?

Comment: seems good but it doesn't work at all the segmentation violation happens earlier than before its very annoying its making me crazy

Answer (score 1):

The required and necessary signature for a thread function to be passed to pthread_create is:

```
void *threadFuntion(void *arg);
```

or, in your case:

```
void *recorreNumero(void *arg);
```

So, the pthread_create call should look like:

```
pthread_create(&t1,NULL,recorreNumero,‌​args);
```

Where 'args' would need to correctly pass [entrada,pro,lineasT] for later consumption by the thread, eg. by declaring a struct with those members, mallocating one, loading up with values and passing the struct ADDRESS as the 'args' argument.  The thread function should cast and dereference the 'arg' to recover those parameters, and could then free the passed struct* when/if it terminates.